# Rudin Chapter 5 Exercise 3

Tags: real-analysis

I think there is an error in the solution below.

I think in the red box, it should be

$(b+\epsilon g(b))-(a+\epsilon g(b))$,

not $(b-\epsilon g(b))-(a-\epsilon g(b))$.

Am I correct?

If I'm correct,

can I continue to say $f(b) - f(a) = (b-a) (1+ \epsilon g'(c))$ is nonzero

,since $b-a$ is nonzero and $1+ \epsilon g'(c)$ is nonzero, and

therefore $f(b) \neq f(a)$ when  $a\neq b$  ?

Is this right?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct, that seems to be a typo in the proof.

Comment: I know we are fixing $\epsilon > 0$, but is there any problem by writing $f'(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f'(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} 1 + \epsilon g'(x) = 1 > 0$? The existence of $f'$ is provided by the existence of $g'$ and the sum of differentiability functions